# jQuery tmpl plugin - Conditional templates?

Tags: jquery, templates, jquery-templates

I'm currently generating a list using the [jQuery tmpl plugin](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/):

```
<script id="mainTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
 <li>
  <a class="Page" href="#" rel="${LINK}" >${DESCRIPTION}</a>
 </li>
</script>
```

Is it at all possible to have things conditionally processed using jQuery templates? I tried:

```
<script id="mainTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
 <li>
 {{if ${TYPE} == "INTLINK" }}
  <a class="Page" href="#" rel="${LINK}" >${DESCRIPTION}</a>
 {{/if}}
 </li>
</script>
```

But it didn't work. I want to be able to conditionally have different template output depending on the data being passed (via json).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no need to wrap TYPE within the if markup. this should work

```
<script id="mainTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <li>
        {{if TYPE == "INTLINK" }}
            <a class="Page" href="#" rel="${LINK}" >${DESCRIPTION}</a>
        {{/if}}
    </li>
</script>
```

assuming your data contains something like {"TYPE": "INTLINK"}.